# Scheme Processing a function n times

Tags: recursion, scheme, row, racket

I'm trying to use the "beside" function in scheme (DrRacket). I'm wondering how I can use recursion to put multiple objects in a row. (define (row n img). The row would be n images long with each image beside each other, stacked horizontally. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a case for [Recursion on the Natural Numbers](http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-15.html)! (I assume you're using [How to Design Programs](http://htdp.org/). If not, consider reading it, because it teaches you a process for solving problems like this.)

Write down some examples. Start with the very simplest example you can think of. The really really very simplest example that you might not even think of ordinarily.

Write down the template for recursion on a natural number argument. Adapt the template to your function (function name, extra argument).

Then think about how to fill in the blanks.

Comment: I am using htdp...we havent gone through this chapter yet, but thank you this helped immensely.